# JQUERY UI Dialog Form is losing buttons actions at close event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

first my code:

```
var form = $("#form_usr");//An empty div to load an html fragment  
var url = (rol==1)?"/page/form1.php":"/page/form2.php";  
form.load(url);
form.dialog({  
    autoOpen: false,  
    open: validator,
    close: cleanner,
    buttons { Ok: save_function, Cancel: function(){$(this).dialog("close")}} 
});
$("#btn_open").click(form.dialog("open"));
```

My problem here is the assigned functions to events and Buttons only work the first time the dialog is opened.

Any advice would be apreciated. 
nt: Sorry about my english

Comment: What does your cleaner function do?

Comment: Your English is perfectly OK :-)

Comment: @eagerMoose nothing special, it just clean the inputs to reuse it.

Comment: I got this little example working http://jsfiddle.net/wVRS4/10/

Comment: the problem seems to be something with the load html function then...

Comment: Can you post a more detailed example?

Comment: the only thing i can think i can add to the example is that the form is modal...

Comment: I've had something similar before. I ended up having to remove the dialog from the DOM using $("#dialogDiv").remove() as it was duplicating itself every time I opened the dialog. You could try something like that, possibly even $("#dialogDiv").dialog("destroy") instead of "close".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buttons { 
  Ok: function() { save_function },
  Cancel: function(){$(this).dialog("close")}
}
```

Does this make it work? :)

Comment: I did a lots of changes to my code, but I think this is why my app is working. Thank's.